# In Google Sheets how to format a cell with date in format "MMMM" (only month name) to Uppercase using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this cell with a date formatted to only display the month name using `MMMM`.
How to use a script in order to format the month name to uppercase while keeping the cell formatted to date? I'm trying to use `toUpperCase()` but it's not working.

I'm trying something like:

```
sheet.getRange(cells[0],1).toUpperCase();
```

Tried to use also `getValues()` in combination with `toUpperCase()` but not working either.

Is there another Javascript or GAS method for doing this or am I doing it wrong?

EDIT:
I want to store the uppercase month name in the cell and I want the cell to remain in date format not text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a formatting option for showing a date in a cell as an *uppercase* month name.

An alternative to using Apps Script would be to **Insert > Column right** and use an array formula in row 1 of the new column:

`=arrayformula(upper(trim(M1:M)))`

The new column would be for viewing only. The date column can remain in place so that you can refer to it in your formulas.

The question specifies Apps Script, so here is how to get the month name in upper case there:

`sheet.getRange(cells[0], 1).getDisplayValue().toUpperCase();`

There is no way to store this uppercase text string in a cell as a numeric date value.

See [Sheets API Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) for more info.

Comment: Ok so with `getDisplayValue()` I don't get an error but the text remains in title case. It won't change to uppercase.

Comment: So I just noticed if I put that line into a variable and use `console.log` I can see the string (is that how you call it?) in uppercase but the month inside the cell remains in title case. Maybe there is a way to get that string and stuck it into the cell, but would that make the cell loose the date format property?

Comment: Yes I just tried it and the cell stops being a date and becomes just text.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide a workaround. Please edit the question to mention that you want to store the uppercase month name in a cell.

Comment: Yes I edited the question thank you.